# Pandas, Timestamp becomes integer (long) when assigning to new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timedelta

df1 has columns of timestamps:

```
df1.dtypes

...
Date datetime64[ns]
...
```

df2 is a new dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[...], index=[...])
```

I iterate through the rows, and at some point(s), assign a timestamp from df1 to df2:

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    ...
    df2['Date'] = row.Date
    ...
```

But the timestamp ends up an integer after assignment...

```
type(row.Date)
# <class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>

type(df2['Date'][loc-I-assigned]) 
# <type 'long'>
```

How do I address this?

Comment: Which version of pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of pandas, and seems will not be fixed in version 1.x, so we have to deal with it by ourselves.
[Pandas Github bug ticket](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15526)

But you can convert it yourself.
Suppose series is an object of pd.Series, you can

`series['Date'] = row.Date
series['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(series['Date'])`

Actually, I think there also something wrong in your code, `df2['Date']` is a Series, but `row.Date` is a value.